# Manybody theory: cancellation contributions to proper polarization

Tags: feynman-diagrams, many-body

I don't understand why the first order diagrams (c) e (d) give null contribute to the correlation energy. We are considering systems of fermions uniform in space and time (we are in momentum space) and the wavy line is an arbitrary potential.
Thank you very much in advance!
[image: diagrams]